# Ghostscript extract text with form feed (page break)

Tags: ghostscript, ghostscript.net

I need to know where the page breaks are in the output file?

```
gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=txtwrite -sOutputFile=output.txt input.PDF
```

**Sorry about my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no page breaks in the output file. Use -sOutputFile=output%d.txt to get each page in a separate file.